# ViewPager in a StickyNestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<me.didik.component.StickyNestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pager"
            android:tag="sticky"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab_layout"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</me.didik.component.StickyNestedScrollView>
```

ViewPager height does not change.
Height is always set to 0.
But if you force the height it will be set.
I want to write both tablelayout and scrollview.

Please help me....

Comment: Welcome @chunmu, please describe your question properly. also add what you have tried, where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

you need to add attribute

`app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab_layout"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

also setting the height 0dp instead 0 will work

Comment: But, I can`t scroll viewpager... how can i do?

Comment: @chunmu are you using fragments in view pager or anything else? And which scrolling you need Horizontal or Vertical .

Comment: ViewPager use fragment, fragment use constranintlayout

Comment: @chunmu try adding android:fillViewport="true" in your StickyNestedScrollView